# php variable scope and fwrite inside function

Tags: php

I'm trying to figure out where my add to cart process is messing up, so i decided to add in some logging code (fwrite) Well then I quickly learned about php variable scope. And now I'm stuck.

The first thing i tried before i learned about variable scope.

```
$fp = fopen('logs/functions.txt', 'w');

function addtocart($pid,$qty){
    fwrite($fp, 'addtocart()\nProduct ID: '. $pid .'\nQuantity: '. $qty .'\n');
    if($pid<1 or $qty<1) return;
    if(is_array($_SESSION['cart'])){
        if(product_exists($pid)) return;
        $max=count($_SESSION['cart']);
        $_SESSION['cart'][$max]['productid']=$pid;
        $_SESSION['cart'][$max]['qty']=$qty;
    }else{
        $_SESSION['cart']=array();
        $_SESSION['cart'][0]['productid']=$pid;
        $_SESSION['cart'][0]['qty']=$qty;
    }
}

fclose($fp);
```

So that returned an error saying something like fp is not defined.

Then i looked up php variable scope. Because if a similar thing were written in another, it may have worked.

I tried declaring $fp global;

```
function addtocart($pid,$qty){
        global $fp;
        fwrite($fp, 'addtocart()\nProduct ID: '. $pid .'\nQuantity: '. $qty .'\n');
```

I get the error "Warning: fwrite(): 3 is not a valid stream resource" like its turning $fp into some sort of integer. Why?

Comment: Where does this `3` come from?

Comment: Make a var_dump on $fp after you open the file, it seems like the file isn't opened.

Comment: Your code should be OK (when using global) - you probably not have write permissions to `logs/functions.txt` ...

Comment: what are you trying to achieved? is it just to write to file?

Comment: Amal: That's what i was wondering. David: I have permission, putting an arbitrary 'write to' outside the function writes to said file. ShapCyber: I'm trying to error log the dumb way. I'm saying this because I don't know what the best way is for what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use fopen inside functions... i think this is best solution, and maybe let the code to create different logging files for each function.

Hope this is helpfull.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this

```
<?php 
$pid=$_SESSION['PID'];
$qty=$_SESSION['QTY'];
$contentToWrite="Product ID:". $pid ."Quantity:". $qty;
$writeToText = "filePathToWriteTo.php";

if (is_writable($writeToText)) {


    if (!$willWrite = fopen($writeToText, 'w')) {
         echo "writeToText Cannot open file ";
         exit;
    }


    if (fwrite($willWrite, $contentToWrite) === FALSE) {
        echo "writeToText Cannot write to this file ".$writeToText;
        exit;
    }
    fclose($willWrite);

} else {
    echo "May be security reasons ".$writeToText." is not writable";
}?>
```

Comment: Thank you for taking time to write this. However, this is just one of multiple functions referencing a session array 'cart' where multiple pid and qty are stored. Could I put all this in the function?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the file handler to the function

```
function addtocart($fp,$pid,$qty){
// your code
}
```

that's the easiest way to do this, according with your code, and much better than use $GLOBALS.

Are you using http://php.net/manual/es/function.error-reporting.php to display the error or you can check the error log of your web server.

Answer (score 0):

A nicer way to do that would be to use the $GLOBALS[] array instead.

I'm not sure if it is possible to use the global-keyword to resources.